# How can I compute $P_{|b\rangle}(|0\rangle)$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises

I've just started to learn Quantum Computing and, to do it, I'm reading the course "[Introduction from Quantum Computing](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/introduction/why-quantum-computing)" by IBM.

Now, I'm reading the chapter "[Entangled states](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/introduction/entangled-states)", section "[Product states](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/introduction/entangled-states#entangled-3-0)" where they show how to compute the probability of measuring the state $|a\rangle$ as $|0\rangle$:

$$P_{|a\rangle}(|0\rangle) = (b_0a_0)^2+(b_1a_0)^2 \\
\begin{gather}
 = b_0^2a_0^2+b_1^2a_0^2 \\
 = (b_0^2+b_1^2)a_0^2 \\
 = a_0^2
\end{gather}$$

And they say that I can compute $P_{|b\rangle}(|0\rangle)$ but, **how?** Changing the order of the amplitudes like this:

$$P_{|b\rangle}(|0\rangle) = (a_0b_0)^2+(a_1b_0)^2 ...$$

But, if so, I don't understand why. I think that, in both cases, we are working on the same state vector $|ba\rangle$, and if I change the amplitude order, I change the state vector to $|ab\rangle$.

How can I compute $P_{|b\rangle}(|0\rangle)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it as the following. The state you are working with is:
$$b_0a_0|00\rangle+b_0a_1|01\rangle+b_1a_0|10\rangle+b_1a_1|11\rangle$$
If we were to measure both qubits, the probability of measuring the state $|BA\rangle$ would be given by $\left(b_Ba_A\right)^2$. In order to compute the probability that the second qubit is in state $|0\rangle$, you simply have to sum up all the probabilities that this qubit is in state $|0\rangle$, had you measured both qubits. In this case, this gives us:
$$p_{|a\rangle}(|0\rangle)=p_{|ba\rangle}(|00\rangle)+p_{|ba\rangle}(|10\rangle)=\left(b_0a_0\right)^2+\left(b_1a_0\right)^2=a_0^2$$.
Similarly, the probability to measure $|0\rangle$ on $|b\rangle$ is given by:
$$p_{|b\rangle}(|0\rangle)=p_{|ba\rangle}(|00\rangle)+p_{|ba\rangle}(|01\rangle)=\left(b_0a_0\right)^2+\left(b_0a_1\right)^2=b_0^2$$
What is important to note is that since $|ba\rangle$ si the product state of $|b\rangle$ and $|a\rangle$ these probabilities are the same as if we were not considering the product state but the states $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ independently.